# Alter fixedPostVars argument with custom userFunc

Tags: realurl, typo3-7.6.x

I have a realurl2 configuration which requires me to change the title of a given category by a selected language. The kicker is there is only one Database Record with the category title and the translation is made trough .xlf files.

I managed to replace the title now, however the mapping obviously does not work. Is there a method within the realurl Classes which could easily add a database record or am I stuck decoding it myself within the $_GET Paramaeters?

```
'fixedPostVars' => array(
        // TODO: Implement dynamic via typoscript if possible!
        '3' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_products_products[product_categories]',
                'userFunc' => function(&$params, $ref) use ($recordTranslator){
                    $categoryId = $params['value'];
                    $translation = $recordTranslator->render('Category', 'title', $categoryId, 'products');
                    $realUrlConf = new \DmitryDulepov\Realurl\Configuration\ConfigurationReader(0, $params);
                    $realUrlUtil = new \DmitryDulepov\Realurl\Utility($realUrlConf);
                    $translation = $realUrlUtil->convertToSafeString($translation);



                    return $translation;
                }
            ),
```

This is what I have coded so far. The recordTranslator here just returns the String I want to use within the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up pre filling my "tx_realurl_uniqalias" table with aliases, field, uid, language, etc.

The Translated Alias still was created trough

```
                $realUrlConf = new \DmitryDulepov\Realurl\Configuration\ConfigurationReader(0, $params);
                $realUrlUtil = new \DmitryDulepov\Realurl\Utility($realUrlConf);
                $translation = $realUrlUtil->convertToSafeString($translation);
```

I mapped my Iso language tags to the spoken language prior to this. For that I created a typoscript object within my settings.

```
de {
       ch-de = 1
       de-de = 3
       at-de = 5
     }
     en {
       de-en = 4
     }
     fr {
       ch-fr = 2
     }
     no {
       no = 6
     }
```

and saved the language field provided by the realurl_conf to filter the translation. Like so:

```
'GETvar' => 'L',
        'valueMap' => array(
            'ch-de' => '1',
            'ch-fr' => '2',
            'de-de' => '3',
            'de-en' => '4',
            'at-de' => '5',
            'no' => '6',
        ),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
```

I still have to clear my SpokenUrl Aliases within the backend whenever a new "Database Record" is created and rebuild it with the refreshed data but it works.

The lookup is the usual lookuptable format:

```
 array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_products_products[product_categories]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tx_products_domain_model_category',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'title',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```